# Why red and IntelliJ not supporting to valid model in Angular?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

"shortName" and "uuid" is exist, contain data in runtime and definated element in object type (interface). Ofc, there is not problem when I am building project. Just, why does IntelliJ say red and why doesn’t it support with possible items?

IntelliJ 2020.3.1

[image]

Comment: might be not supported from IntelliJ,
IntelliJ IDEA supports .TS and .TSX files for sure

Comment: I have fixed it with full PC restart. :) And Its been good.

Answer (score 0):

A full machine reboot solved it